# two recursive sequences and the limit of their quotient

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

The sequences $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}$ and $\left \{ b_{n} \right \}$  are defined by the following recurrence relations:

1. $a_{1}=b_{1}=1$
2. $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+2b_{n}$
3. $b_{n+1}=a_{n}+b_{n}$

What is the limit of $\displaystyle \{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\}$ as n goes to infinity?

Comment: is $b_n=1$? what does it mean?

Comment: You mean $a_1=b_1=1$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner it is $b_1=1$, sorry for my misleading mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good idea for this problem is to write $\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$ in terms of $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$.

$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac{a_n+2b_n}{a_n+b_n}=1+\frac{b_n}{a_n+b_n}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{a_n+b_n}{b_n}}=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{a_n}{b_n}}$.

Now we write the sequence of numbers in the form $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ as $c_n$. We get the recursion $c_{n+1}=1+\frac{1}{1+c_n}=\frac{2+c_n}{1+c_n}$

If a recursion converges to something, that means that it will eventually be really really close to that, which means that it basically does not change already (the changes become infinitesmal). So basically we solve $\frac{2+c_n}{1+c_n}=c_n$, which is $2+c_n=c_n+c_n^2$, so $c_n=\pm \sqrt{2}$. However, if $c_n$ is positive, then $c_{n+1}$ is positive. $c_1$ is positive, so it can't converge to $-\sqrt{2}$. Hence it converges to $\boxed{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: should we prove that the $ \{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}\} $ converges?

Comment: Yes, I was actually thinking about that. but idk how.

Comment: With a similar argument you can show that $\sqrt 2 > (2+c)/(1+c) > c$ for $-\sqrt 2 < c < \sqrt 2$. So $(c_n)$ is increasing and bounded above, and therefore convergent.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=1+\frac{1}{\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}+1}$$

So if $x$ serves indeed as limit for $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ then it should satisfy...